# How do I properly loop this in HTML?

Tags: html, for-loop, google-maps, coordinates

I know very little about HTML but I am tasked to try to find a solution to make this code more efficient.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fcTm.png)

I have coordinates for signs in different districts, it is limited to 6 but can be even up to 50 later on. `coDist1 -> coDist6` variables have been created, and all values are the same but the colors need to change for each.

To save time and be more efficient I want to have a for loop, but I am struggling to conceptualize

- how to make the for loop have n length (how do I count the districts) and
- how to display the values inside the loop (all values are the same except the colors that change)

Thank you for any advice/help

Edit: This is the code for 1 district

```js
var coDist1Coords = 
  [ { lat: 32.821687, lng: -85.21314 }
  , { lat: 32.820244, lng: -85.21176 }
  , { lat: 32.821182, lng: -85.20996 }
  , { lat: 32.821182, lng: -85.20782 }
  , { lat: 32.82111,  lng: -85.20576 }
  , { lat: 32.821903, lng: -85.20378 }
  , { lat: 32.822696, lng: -85.20181 }
  , { lat: 32.823418, lng: -85.20035 }
  ];
 
var coDist1 = new google.maps.Polygon(
  { paths         : coDist1Coords
  , strokeColor   : 'red'
  , strokeOpacity : 0.8
  , strokeWeight  : 2
  , fillColor     : 'red'
  , fillOpacity   : 0.35 
  });
```

I have tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
var color = ['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'orange', 'brown']

for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    var coDist[i]= new google.maps.Polygon(
    paths: coDist[i]Coords,
    strokeColor: color[i],
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: color[i],
    fillOpacity: 0.35
    )
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - you will find that you will get more help by posting a minimal, reproducible example of your error or query - so please share the code you have so far, what you've tried and what issues you're facing - then I'm sure someone will answer this pretty quickly :)

Comment: Thank you, I shared a bit of it, there is some more but this covers what I want to make more efficient. I have tried adding a for loop but I can't figure out how to get the length of the districts. Also, I am trying to change the colors inside the loop but I am not sure how to go about that

Answer (score 0):

you can use an IIFE function to prtoct your code:

```js
const getColor = (() =>
  {
  const colors = ['red','blue','green', 'orange', 'grey', 'yellow' ];
  let   indx   = -1 + colors.length;
  
  return { 
    new() 
      {
      indx = ++indx % colors.length // circurlar loop on colors
      return colors[indx]
      },
    current()
      {
      return colors[indx]
      }
    }
  })()
```

usage:

```js
var XXX = new google.maps.Polygon(
  { paths         : coDist1Coords
  , strokeColor   : getColor.new()     // <-- get new color 
  , strokeOpacity : 0.8
  , strokeWeight  : 2
  , fillColor     : getColor.current() // <-- get current color 
  , fillOpacity   : 0.35 
  });
```

if you want to test / verify...

```js
const getColor = (() =>
  {
  const colors = ['red','blue','green', 'orange', 'grey', 'yellow' ];
  let indx     = -1 + colors.length;
  return { 
    new() 
      {
      indx = ++indx % colors.length // circurlar loop on colors
      return colors[indx]
      },
    current()
      {
      return colors[indx]
      }
    }
  })()

let num = 0
console.log( ++num, getColor.new(),  getColor.current() ) 
console.log( ++num, getColor.new(),  getColor.current() ) 
console.log( ++num, getColor.new(),  getColor.current() ) 
console.log( ++num, getColor.new(),  getColor.current() ) 
console.log( ++num, getColor.new(),  getColor.current() ) 
console.log( ++num, getColor.new(),  getColor.current() ) 
console.log( ++num, getColor.new(),  getColor.current() ) 
console.log( ++num, getColor.new(),  getColor.current() ) 
console.log( ++num, getColor.new(),  getColor.current() )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

So let's push all your districts with their coordinates in an array calles `listDistrictCoordinates`. So that it will become a list that contains all your district variables. If we then want to know/use the coordinates from lets say the first district in our list, then all we need to call is `listDistrictCoordinates[0]`.

Let's also push all your colors in an array called `listColors`. If we then need to use the first color we can just call `listColors[0]`.

The same way we can use an array that contains all these variables for the goolge maps polygons, lets call that one `listDistrictPolygons`. As we want to use a loop to create those polygon variables, we first create an empty list. Then after we create the polygon variable for each district we will add/push that polygon variable in the list (array). So after the loop that creates all those polygon variables for each districht we will endup with a list with all districtPolygon variables. And the first districtPolygon variable in the `listDistrictPolygons`is the one corresponding with the first districtCoordinates in the `listDistrictCoordinates`.

If you want to check the first districtCoordinate in your list use `listDistrictCoordinates[0]` If you want to check the first districtPolygon in the other list use `listDistrictPolygons[0]`. And for the second one use [1], etc.

```js
/* 
   Create your variables coordinates
   call the first one district0,
   then  they'll al be the same number in the array 
*/
let district0Coordinates = 
    [ { lat: 32.821687, lng: -85.21314 }
  , { lat: 32.820244, lng: -85.21176 }
  , { lat: 32.821182, lng: -85.20996 }
  , { lat: 32.821182, lng: -85.20782 }
  , { lat: 32.82111,  lng: -85.20576 }
  , { lat: 32.821903, lng: -85.20378 }
  , { lat: 32.822696, lng: -85.20181 }
  , { lat: 32.823418, lng: -85.20035 }
  ];


let district1Coordinates = 
    [ { lat: 33.821687, lng: -86.21314 }
  , { lat: 33.820244, lng: -86.21176 }
  , { lat: 33.821182, lng: -86.20996 }
  , { lat: 33.821182, lng: -86.20782 }
  , { lat: 33.82111,  lng: -86.20576 }
  , { lat: 33.821903, lng: -86.20378 }
  , { lat: 33.822696, lng: -86.20181 }
  , { lat: 33.823418, lng: -86.20035 }
  ];



/* 
   Create your arrays,
   You can fill the ones for your coordinates and your colors.
   You'll need an empty one for your polygons 
   (as they still need to be created by a loop)
 */
let listDistrictCoordinates = [district0Coordinates, district1Coordinates];
let listColors = ['red', 'blue'];
let listDistrictPolygons = [];


/*
    Use a loop to create the districtPolygons.
  It will loop as often as there are variable coordinates in the listDistrictCoordinates
  If we looping through the first coordinates (i==0)  we will use
  the first element in the listDistrictCoordinates[0] and the listColors[0]
  If we're looping through the second district coordinates (i==1)
  the second element from the listDistrictCoordinates[1] and listColors[1] is used 
*/
for(let i=0; i<listDistrictCoordinates.length; i++) {
    let districtPolygon =  new google.maps.Polygon(
  { paths         : listDistrictCoordinates[i]
  , strokeColor   : listColors[i]
  , strokeOpacity : 0.8
  , strokeWeight  : 2
  , fillColor     : listColors[i]
  , fillOpacity   : 0.35 
  });
  
  listDistrictPolygons.push(districtPolygon);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is so much easier to understand and what I was trying to do in the first place.